# Symfony + Doctrine - UnitOfWork commit order

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a form that shows entity:

```
class Event
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * 
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="EventAttendee", mappedBy="event", cascade={"all"})
     */
    private $attendees;
}
```

and a collection within it:

```
class EventAttendee
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Event", inversedBy="attendees")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="event_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $event;

    /**
     * 
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Employee")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="employee_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $employee;
}
```

If I delete an employee from the collection and add it again, I'm getting integrity constraint violation. This is because Doctrine's UnitOfWork first executes Inserts and then Deletes. Therefore, when it inserts a new record db still has the old one with the same employee.

Doctrine2 developers did not provide any working solution for Symfony2 users (here is the thread: http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-601).

And thus, I'm asking the question here: is it anyhow possible to avoid this issue?

EDIT:

My current workaround is:

1. find all not-persisted colletion items ready to insert
2. remove them from the collection and save to a variable
3. remove all the items that were really deleted in the form
4. call flush()
5. add all the items for insert back to the collection
6. call flush()

This works for me, however doesn't look good. Maybe someone has a better solution.